# Build LuaJIT for android. NDK. Windows

Tags: windows, android-ndk, luajit

I can't build LuaJIT for Android under Windows. Here is my batch file.

```
set NDK=c:/android-ndk-r10d
set NDKABI=14
set NDKVER=%NDK%/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
set NDKP=%NDKVER%/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
set NDKF=--sysroot %NDK%/platforms/android-%NDKABI%/arch-arm
set NDKARCH=-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
make HOST_CC="gcc -m32" CROSS="%NDKP%" TARGET_FLAGS="%NDKF% %NDKARCH%"
```

Output:

```
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDK=c:/android-ndk-r10d
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDKABI=14
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDKVER=c:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDKP=c:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDKF=--sysroot c:/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>set NDKARCH=-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
C:\LuaJIT-2.0.3\src>make HOST_CC="gcc -m32" CROSS="c:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-" TARGET_FLAGS="--sysroot c:/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
"HOSTCC    host/minilua.o"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -m32 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -I. -DLUAJIT_TARGET=LUAJIT_ARCH_arm -DLJ_ARCH_HASFPU=1 -DLJ_ABI_SOFTFP=1 -c -o host/minilua.o host/minilua.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [host/minilua.o] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a file missing. Have you verified they are present?

Comment: @ThomasKilian seems I need to build `host/minilua`

Comment: Build messages are always a bit cryptic...

Comment: LuaJIT needs to build a small Lua interpreter called `minilua` in order to build itself. With the makefile, it attempts to do this using regular GCC, but you don't have it installed. You can either install MinGW+MSys, or set `HOST_LUA` to the path to a locally built installation of LuaJIT (ex. compiled with visual studio)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks, HOST_LUA option helped. Now I have same error with host/buildvm.o. I can compile it with msvc but what option is assigned with it?

Comment: If you're using MSVC to build LuaJIT you need to run the `msvcbuild` script inside the `src/` directory, not the makefile. See [the Building on Windows section](http://luajit.org/install.html)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm under win 7 and I need luajit as static library for Android.

Comment: And in order to do so, you need GCC for your host system so that LuaJIT can compile minilua to use to generate some files that it needs to build. But you don't have GCC, so you need to compile LuaJIT for your host system using MSVC to replace minilua.